# Div height equal to another div max-height

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

- Div "one" contains some content so its height is 300px for example.
- Div "two" contains more or less content so its height is 400px for example.
- Both content is changing, it's not static so I cannot calculate
  heights manually.
- Style of div "two" will also contain "overflow-y: scroll;"

How to create div "two" to be same height as div "one" which can be smaller or bigger?

Here is a quick sketch:

[image: Simple sketch]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Javascript, you could do something like:

```
document.getElementById("two").style.height = document.getElementById("one").clientHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set both div "one" and div "two" to have a height of 100%, you can control the height of both of them via the style of the outer div, and you are guaranteed that they always have the same height.

If you always want div "two" to be as high as div "one" **or shorter**, here's some JavaScript code that may help you:

```
document.getElementById("two").style.maxHeight = document.getElementById("one").style.height;
```

Answer (score 1):

Via Javascript  http://jsfiddle.net/D6bMJ/1/ (automatically set the #main height to the #one height)
or CSS, manually define a height for the #main which would be the highest between #one and #two. : http://jsfiddle.net/D6bMJ/2/  (#two has height:100%, so the same height as it's parent).

Answer (score 1):

This will work both if div one is higher then div two and the opposite (with jQuery) and will also be fired every time you resize the window (for fluid layouts):

```
resize_objects();
$(window).resize(resize_objects);

function resize_objects(){
var $a = $('#one').height(), $b = $('#two').height();

if($a > $b) {
    //#one is higher than #two
    $("#two").css("height",$a);
}
else {
    //#two is higher than #one
    $("#one").css("height",$b);
    }
}
```