# Overflow DIV content without fix height

Tags: html, css-float, css

I have two divs: left and right. In the left there is a long text. In the right there are some annotations about the text (more divs). If the text of the left is longer than the annotations I'm like it. But when the annotations are bigger/longer then the left div, I want to make the right div's content overflow.

With other words: two divs without fix height, make overflow the right one.

The code is above or [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/borazslo/B2cch/)

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">Some long-long text, allways to show</div>
    <div id="right">Some divs not necessarily show all</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container {
    background-color:white;
    float:left;
}

#left {
  width: 79%;
  float:left;
}

#right {
  width: 19%; 
  float:right;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

But it's not working. :(

Comment: here: [JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/borazslo/B2cch/)

Comment: For clarification, you'd like the left div to expand with its content indefinitely, and the right div to expand up to that height of the left div, but no further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jan suggested in his last comment, I think you need to use javascript or jQuery to accomplish this.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672433/div-height-equal-to-another-div-max-height) outlines an approach using javascript that was accepted by the OP, though the OP made no comments on his process of execution.

I've modified a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8VAT7/) from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9672633/2183554) to a similar question.

It uses the following:

CSS

```
#main{
    width:auto;    

}

#one{
height:auto;
width:200px;
display:inline-block;
float:left;

}
#two{
height:100%;
width:200px;
float:left;
display:inline-block;
overflow: auto;

}

div{
border:1px solid black;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#main").css("height",$("#one").height());


 });
```

And I believe addresses your desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use overflow: hidden on #left, and not on #right.

Comment: Sorry it not so easy. :( (Perhaps I made the text of the divs be misunderstood, so i changed them.)

Comment: Do you have an more detailed version of your code, maybe on http://jsfiddle.net/ like @mikeswright49 proposed?

Comment: And how about the semantic value. Could you speak of tabulair data? In other words, is the use of a table eventually appropriate?

Comment: The problem remains the same: <tr id="container"><td id="left"></td><td id="right"></td></tr>

Comment: I guess you should use javascript to get the height of div#left, and apply it to div#right. If you then use overflow hidden, it should work.