# Responsive menu in a div design issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have  [**this layout**](http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/6044/z169.jpg)

I have 2 problems:

- The height of `div` 2 is not same as `div` 1 or 3, i tried    [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672433/div-height-equal-to-another-div-max-height)
  from stack overflow, but its not working.
- The menu to be set in `div` 2 is responsive, but on shrinking the width, it
  list down, which pushes the carousel even below, screwing the whole
  design..... 
   is there any method i can make the `mid_div` responsive
  by not shrinking but instead create a horizontal scroll in that `div`
  only (depending on screen size) ??

**CSS**

```css
#h_scroll {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 80%;
}

#h_scroll_banner {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

#h_scroll .fltlft {
    float: left
}

#h_scroll .fltryt { 
    float: right
}

#h_scroll .mid_div {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F11181;
    height: 100%;
}

#h_scroll .mid_div ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#h_scroll .mid_div li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

#h_scroll .mid_div li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 20%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 4%;
    width: 20%;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div id="h_scroll">
    <div id="h_scroll_banner">            
        <div class="fltlft" id="div_height_to_get">         
            <img src="image/scroll_banner_left.jpg" style="width:100%; height:auto" id="div_height_to_get" />
        </div>

        <div class="fltryt">
            <img src="image/scroll_banner_right.jpg" style="width:100%; height:auto" />
        </div>

        <div class="mid_div" id="div_height_to_set">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#nogo"> Links </a></li>
                <li><a href="#nogo"> Links </a></li>
                <li><a href="#nogo"> Links </a></li>
                <li><a href="#nogo"> Links </a></li>
                <li><a href="#nogo"> Links </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: (looking at SO styling for css code) So thaaat's why styling ID's is bad...

Comment: Have you looked at fixing the height of the div and setting the overflow-y: scroll; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have full control over the source, here is my solution ([JSFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4gPG/1/)):

***HTML***

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="banner-left"></div>
    <div class="banner-mid">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="banner-right"></div>
    <p>This is some content under the menu</p>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
.wrapper {
    margin: 40px auto;
    width: 600px;
}
.banner-left, .banner-right {
    background: #eee;
    float:left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
.banner-left {
    margin-left: -50px;
}
.banner-right{
    margin-right: -50px;
}
.banner-mid {
    float:left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
.banner-mid > ul {
    background: #ddd;
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
.banner-mid > ul > li {
    float:left;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: hi jkinz, this webpage is supposed to be responsive.....putting pixel value in CSS will solve it for PC but would render it non-responsive! :(

Comment: You can change to use percentages where appropriate. The two banner ends are images with set widths I would imagine, so I'd say using pixels there would be alright. Then just use a responsive style sheet to replace them if you have smaller version.

Answer (score 0):

Since your banner flairs don't have any content in them, why not use a `::before` and `::after`? I don't see the need why all 3 divs need to be the same height and using generated content you can just have the slideshow positioned based on margins from `.mid_div`.

```
.mid_div {
    position: relative;
}

.mid_div::before, .mid_div::after {
    display:block
    width: 50px; /*  image width  */
    height: 50px; /*  image height  */
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -50px;
    background: url(image/scroll_banner_left.jpg); 
}

.mid_div::after {
    left: 100%;
    background: url(image/scroll_banner_right.jpg);
}
```

As for you wanting a scrollbar, use `overflow-x: auto` on the `.mid_div` and for the `.mid_div ul` have a set pixel `width` for it and whenever `.mid_div` gets smaller the content won't reflow. You could also try `white-space: nowrap` on the `ul` also while having the `li {display: inline}`.

Comment: coverage is pretty good across the board: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent . Since it's decorative and looking at < IE7, you can always decide if it's needed and then you could always generate it with js while targeting the older browsers.

Comment: Hey Mayank, it's just CSS, take a look here http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent and you'll see that `::before & ::after` are covered by 94% of the browsers shown except for IE8 which you'll then have to use `:before & :after` (1 semi-colon instead of 2, though if you use 1 most modern browsers will interpret it as ::)

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your first question, making all the divs the same height, you need to do this:

```
div1, div2, div3 { display: table-cell; }
```

For your second answer you could apply a min width to the divs/div and set the overflow to scroll.

Comment: i applied table cell...here is output : http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/7721/6ef.png <br/>
CSS <br >
#h_scroll_banner {display:inline-block;width:100%;}
#h_scroll_banner .fltlft{float:left;display: table-cell; }
#h_scroll_banner .fltryt{float:right;display: table-cell; }
#h_scroll_banner .mid_div{width:100%;background-color:#F11181;;display:table-cell  }

Comment: @mayanksingh When you use table-cell you don't need to use float anymore. It would align all three divs like the cells of a table, which I suppose is what your ultimate aim is.

Comment: @mayanksingh Can you create a fiddle with this. I could help better that way.